# Unresolved Reference findViewById

Tags: android, kotlin

My findViewbyId is coming up as a unresolved reference here is how I wanted to use it.
[image]

I wanted it to read the button that has been made in one of my fragments but it seems to not like the findViewById method. im not sure what to do next.

Comment: Your code needs to be in the `onViewCreated` function, and you can use the passed root `view` as the receiver, so it is like `view.findViewById(...)`